# How to in R select rows that partly appear multiple of X times?

Tags: r

Hi i have a count table like this:

```
         A,   B,  C,  D, 
 X11_1,  0,  10,  9,  4,
 X11_2,  4,  12,  8,  2,
 X11_3,  0,   9,  9,  13,
 X2_1,   7,   0,  3,  3,
 X2_2,   0,  10,  0,  0,
 X21_1,  2,  10,  0,  40,
 X21_2,  3,   0,  0,  0,
 X21_3,  1,   3,  9,  0,
 etc
```

But not al subject (rownames) have been to all 3 measuring moments so I want to delete all that only showed up two or one time. But i cant figure it out. As a result i would like something like this: (X2_* removed because its only occures 2 times)

```
         A,   B,  C,  D, 
 X11_1,  0,  10,  9,  4,
 X11_2,  4,  12,  8,  2,
 X11_3,  0,   9,  9,  13,
 X21_1,  2,  10,  0,  40,
 X21_2,  3,   0,  0,  0,
 X21_3,  1,   3,  9,  0,
 etc
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be realy helpfull. Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Calculate the length of each group and subset to those for which that length exceeds 2.  No packages are used:

```
nr <- nrow(DF)
grp <- sub("_.*", "", rownames(DF))  # extract part before _
subset(DF, ave(1:nr, grp, FUN = length) > 2)
```

giving:

```
       A  B C  D
 X11_1 0 10 9  4
 X11_2 4 12 8  2
 X11_3 0  9 9 13
 X21_1 2 10 0 40
 X21_2 3  0 0  0
 X21_3 1  3 9  0
```

**2)** Another approach is to assume that the part after the underscore is labelled 1, 2, 3, ... as in the question.  Split the rownames into a two column data frame `r`, subset `r` down to the rows whose second column, `V2`, is 3 and then keep only the rows of `DF` corresponding to the first column, `V1`, of `r` in that subset.  No packages are used.

```
r <- read.table(text = rownames(DF), sep = "_")
DF[r$V1 %in% subset(r, V2 == 3)$V1, ]
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- "A,   B,  C,  D, 
 X11_1,  0,  10,  9,  4,
 X11_2,  4,  12,  8,  2,
 X11_3,  0,   9,  9,  13,
 X2_1,   7,   0,  3,  3,
 X2_2,   0,  10,  0,  0,
 X21_1,  2,  10,  0,  40,
 X21_2,  3,   0,  0,  0,
 X21_3,  1,   3,  9,  0,"
DF <- read.csv(text = Lines, strip.white = TRUE)[-5]
```